# Download and offline install all android studio components

Tags: android-studio

After I install the android studio which has 900+mb file size, it still ask for additional downloads of components like Android SDK, and Emulator etc. Im just renting in cafe's and download all I need and install in my pc coz I dont have internet in my house.

Is it possible to download these components manually and install manually, so that the android studio will recognize the components and stop askin for additional downloads?

Everytime I open it asks to download below SDK component (Total Downloaf Size : 1.13 GB)

- Android Emulator,
- Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3,
- Android SDK Platform 28,
- Android SDK. Platform-Tools,
- Android SDK Tools,
- Android Support Repository,
- Google Repository,
- SDK Patch Applier v4,
- Sources for Android 28

Answer (score 0):

You can download / install those dependencies separately, but you need to find the download link one by one which is quite tedious. Probably delegating **Android Studio** / **SDK Manager** to do this for you is the best option.